# best practice of using listview with different layout

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-fragments, scrollview

I am facing an annoying problem:

I have a tab host, inside it I have added a view pager
inside the view pager there is three pages

In the first page I have to add two list view below each other with some other controls, as I know for search that I can't do that because I need the scrolling to be for all view , after a lot of search I have found some people recommend to calculate the list size myself and change list height in the layout param, I am using the following code :

```
public class NonScrollableListView extends ListView {
    private android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams     params;
    private int old_count = 0;
    private int item_height = -1;
    private int divider_height = -1;
    private boolean isDrawn = false;
    public NonScrollableListView(Context context) { super(context); }

    public NonScrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isDrawn == false) {
            if (item_height == -1 && getCount() > 0 && getChildAt(0) != null) {
                item_height = getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            }
            if (divider_height == -1 && getCount() > 0 && getChildAt(0) != null) {
                divider_height = getDividerHeight();
            }
            Log.i("YARAB", ""+ canvas);
            Log.i("YARAB", ""+ getCount());
            if (getCount() != old_count) {
                old_count = getCount();
                params = getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (getCount() * item_height) + (getCount() * divider_height);
                setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            isDrawn = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

it is working fine and calculate the list height, but now it take a lot of time to render my list and swap between fragments, can any one help here.

Comment: You can calculate the list height when the vertical scroll happens with a OnScrollListener

Comment: I already calculate in in onDraw before showing it to the screen, because I am adding my list views inside scrollview.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, but `NonScrollableListView` doesn't sound right. If you don't want to scroll then why use a `ListView` at all?

Comment: I want to be able to add two list views inside scroll view and draw all items of list views and make the scrolling only available for the scroll view.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail That is not possible, you cannot nest scrollable `Views`. Is there any particular reason why you don't just display everything in one big `ListView`?

Comment: @XaverKapeller : because each list is dealing with different object, and is using different adapter.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : I am facing the same problem with GridView, as I have to add two grid views and each grid view has different number of columns and the scrolling must be on the whole view.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail Just combine everything into one `Adapter`. You can deal with multiple different objects/layouts in one `Adapter` without any problems.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : can you support me with a tutorial to explain how to be able to use listview with different layouts? and if you have any idea on how to solve gridview problem please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using one `ListView` to contain everything. If you need to have two types of rows, just define a `Custom ListView` with multiple custom XML layouts to account for the different types of rows.

See [this tutorial for an example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: can you support me with a tutorial to explain how to be able to use listview with different layouts.

Comment: No need to create a custom listview for supporting multiple views, your adapter getView method should simply return the kind of view you need. Android ListView and GridView have lots of logic behind the scenes to make sure the convertView is of the correct type too so you should not even need to pass up on that capability either.